# How to calculate AUC under twoClassSummary?

Tags: r, r-caret, roc, auc

here is my code:

```
train <- data.frame(***contain label, feature group 1 and feature group 2***)

formula <- label ~ features group 1

ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                     number = 10,
                     repeats = 5,
                     summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                     classProbs = T)

fit <- train(formula,
             data = train, 
             method = "glm", 
             metric = "ROC",
             trControl = ctrl,
             na.action = na.omit)

pred <- predict(fit, train)
```

my question is: How to calculate the AUC of `pred`?

I ve tried prSummary, ROCR and pROC, didn't work, it seems like that I can not calculate AUC when both of the obs and pred are exactly the same(levels-wise).

I m wondering if I can train with AUC as metric, how can I can't show the AUC?

p.s.

```
> levels(train$label)
[1] "classA" "classB"
> levels(as.factor(pred))
[1] "classA" "classB"
```

btw what I am doing is: fit multiple algo with caret and rank them by AUC, then I can choose the optimal one (base on AUC).

*reproducible example:

train set: iris

feature g1: first 2 features

feature g2: last 2 features

seed: 123*

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. What didn't work, what did you try?

Comment: This auc is based on the train set and is of little relevance in model selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this one could be the possible answer but I am not so sure if it s right, tell me if i m wrong.

```
response = as.factor(as.numeric(train$label))

predictor = as.vector(as.numeric(pred))

library(pROC)

result = as.numeric(roc(response, predictor)$auc)
```

btw since pROC run very slow, can anyone help me to convert this under ROCR package? thx a lot :)

Comment: What do you mean "pROC run very slow"? It is at least as fast as ROCR. See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cutpointr/vignettes/cutpointr.html#benchmarks for an independent benchmark (and a faster alternative, if that's important to you).

Comment: thank you for the info! then it s fine for me to use pROC now :) I already set up an example, i ve tried ROCR and prSummary by jut put those 2 (response and predictor) in, but went our error :(

Comment: @Calimo btw here is the info i got. https://gist.github.com/traversc/1446ebe1dcc2d84bccdca781d4f1fa2a